# js script works only when alert is present - not an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

An OnClick event calls the following datepicker function.  If an alert is present then, it works fine.  Otherwise, it does not show the calender as required.  Is this a timing issue?

```
function changeStartDate(Item){  
            alert ("alert goes here");

  $("#datepicker_" + Item).datepicker({                  
   dateFormat: 'M-dd-yy',
   onClose: function(dataText, inst){
      newDate = dataText;
                       processDateChange(newDate);
   },
  }); 

  flag = 1; 
  }
```

Where it is called from:

```
 '<div class="InfoBoxLong" id="StartDate_' + TransactionOrderItemID + '"><input id="datepicker_' + TransactionOrderItemID + '" type="text" size="9" id="StartDate_' +  TransactionOrderItemID + '" onClick="changeStartDate(\'' + TransactionOrderItemID + '\')"  value="' + ActivationStartDate + '"> </input></div>' +
```

Comment: Would you show us what position do you put alert to?

Comment: I tried this on a new page with only a datepicker and the script and it works fine. What else could be going on on your page? Perhaps a focus or blur event ? alerts will trigger those

Comment: There are several other functions but none for onFocus, or OnBlur.  
OnClick show datepicker, that is the objective.  The function is called, but the datepicker is not shown immediately or consistently.

Answer (score 3):

Possible the calender DOM hasn't finished rendering - adding an alert() blocks the page which gives it time to finish rendering. Use the equivalent of jquery.ready (http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) to render the calender and then only show it (rather than rendering it) on the onclick event.

Comment: You are probably right.  But, I am not sure about the ready equivalent for this.

Comment: Well I see you are using $("#datepicker_" + Item), and with the $ it's likely you're using either jQuery or Prototype as a supporting library. Do you know which one it might be?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the onClick event to onMouseOver event, and it seems to work fine.  Although, I am not comfortable using it, as it will fireoff this event often.  Thanks for all the responses.