# Why code works if alert statement is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#doctorLists").click(function(){
    $("#doctorListsDisplay").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if ( $('#doctorListsDisplay').is(':hidden')) {
            //alert ('hidden');
            $('#searchMP').css({ top: $("#doctorLists").position().top + 40 }).show();
            if ($('#searchMPDisplay').is(':visible')) {
                alert("MP visible");
                $('#searchMPDisplay').css({ top: $("#searchMP").position().top + 30 }).show();
            }
            value +=180;
            $('#imgArrowDown').rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
        else {
            //alert ('shown');
            $('#searchMP').css({ top: $("#doctorLists").position().top + 230 }).show();
            if ($('#searchMPDisplay').is(':visible')) {
                alert("MP hidden");
                $('#searchMPDisplay').css({ top: $("#searchMP").position().top + 30 }).show();
            }
            value +=180;
            $('#imgArrowDown').rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
    });
});
```

The only time the following lines of code works, is if the alert statement is not commented out:

```
if ($('#searchMPDisplay').is(':visible')) {
    alert("visible");
    $('#searchMPDisplay').css({ top: $("#searchMP").position().top + 30 }).show();
}
```

and

```
if ($('#searchMPDisplay').is(':visible')) {
    alert("hidden");
    $('#searchMPDisplay').css({ top: $("#searchMP").position().top + 30 }).show();
}
```

I added the alert statement to see the status but now if i delete it, the code does not work. Can someone help me figure out why?

[image][image][image]

Comment: the alert changing the outcome indicates that something asynchronous is impacting the code, such as an animation or an ajax request. Please, do not use alerts to debug code, use the console. This is why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [js script works only when alert is present - not an ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505379/js-script-works-only-when-alert-is-present-not-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I do have a slider being displayed also in the page. So what would be the best way to overcome the issue?

Comment: First, figure out what the issue is. At this point we have no idea other than it's based on an animation or an ajax call. or a setTimeout.

Comment: What other information would you need to help me solve this issue?

Comment: Elaborate on *"the code does not work"* Why doesn't the code work?

Comment: I will update my question with images to better explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible explanation is that alert hangs code execution until the elements which you are trying to show/hide are added to DOM.

The best way to debug your code is to add `console.log` instead of alerts, with information is elements are already in DOM.

Comment: So how would I fix the issue?

Comment: I will wait for document ready event or use setTimeout if elements are not in DOM. You could look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722791/wait-or-sleep-function-in-jquery